# returning data from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The query is to choose the departure and the destination's catered for coaches and result in any combination for the data selected

This query is in the file: getPullman.php

```
include '../Includes/config.php';
$nomeArrivo=$_POST['nomeA'];
$nomePartenza=$_POST['nomeP'];
$sql="SELECT codl,fermatap,fermataa,ora
      FROM partenza,arrivo,orari,
      WHERE idp=codp,
      AND codo=ido,
      AND fermatap='$nomePartenza',
      AND fermataa='$nomeArrivo'";



$result=$conn->query($sql);


echo "<table>";
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['codl']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['fermatap']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['fermataa']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['ora']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";

$conn->close();
```

Comment: And ... your question is?

Comment: You should be using prepared statements to give you more protection from SQL injection

Comment: So what's the problem, that you've faced with?

Answer (score -1):

Just write below like of code where you want result of this query.

`include_once('getPullman.php');`

Or you can check file path of "getPullman.php" and can write whole path.